# What is the difference between useRoute and useRouter in Nuxt3-Vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I want to understand, what is the difference between

```js
const Route = useRoute()
```

and

```js
const Router = useRouter()
```

in Nuxt3/Vue.

Also, I am not able to use router properly.

on submit, I want to push to another page with query strings using.

```html
<template>
  <button @click="SearchTaxi"></button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const router = useRouter()
const pickuppoint = ref('')
const dropoffpoint = ref('')

const SearchTaxi = () => {
router.push({
  path: `/airport-transfers/results?pickuppoint=${pickuppoint.value}&dropoffpoint=${dropoffpoint.value}`})
}
</script>
```

I expect route to change to

```
"url/airport-transfers/results?pickuppoint=XXXX&dropoffpoint=XXXX"
```

but i am getting

```
"url/airport-transfers/results"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 things:

- route, which will contain all the info related to the path, hostname, current query params etc...
- router, the actual Vue router that will provide you all the features such as a client side navigation (with `push` or `replace`), rollback to the `n-1`,  resolve etc...

You can check the API: https://router.vuejs.org/api/
And see which methods/fields are available on each one of them.

If you want to push some query params and a new path, you could use the following

```js
router.push({
  path: '/airport-transfers/results',
  query: { 
    pickuppoint: pickuppoint.value,
    dropoffpoint: dropoffpoint.value
  }
})
```

As explained here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location